# Regarding <mat-toolbar> in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Will mat-toolbar in angular continue in all the components/pages of the application?
Does it continue in all the components of the application?

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Welcome to Conflux Application</span>
</mat-toolbar-row>
```

Will this come to all the components on Routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, let's say, in your app.component.html, you have the following:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>Welcome</span>
</mat-toolbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

all subsequent page routes will populate in the router-outlet tag, leaving your toolbar visible to all pages.

Answer (score 0):

its not about `<mat-toolbar>` its just a normal html tag like `<b><i>` coming to your question since its a angular application `app.component.html` will act as a default component if you have used `<mat-toolbar>` inside the `app.component.html` then it will be used all the subsequent pages..

you can find more details below 
https://angular.io/guide/file-structure